# Overwrite global font-size: 62%

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I created a little browser extension that is rendering an overlay button to the linkedin.com website. Everything working fine so far - but when trying it out, I realised, that LinkedIn is using somehow a global `font-size: 62,5%` that is breaking my whole layout ..
[image]

When disabling the global font-size scaling, my overlay button looks just fine.

I was trying to overwrite this setting in several places with a `font-size: 100% !important` - without any success.
I'm not that experienced with CSS, so I thought maybe that someone has more creative ideas on solving this problem :)

The overlay looks like this:
[image]

And is expected to look more like this:
[image]

I'm using Material-UI to build the design elements.

Answer (score 1):

When font-size is set in percentage it is relative to the parent. So setting it to 100% is just keeping it the same size as the parent. Try setting it to a fixed size, e.g. 16px, or something more than 100% to compensate, e.g. 1.6rem or 160%, or something.

Comment: that is actually already a very good hint, thank you! Do you have another idea on how to maybe reset all CSS settings from the outside CSS files? As you can see, not only the font-size, but also the border settings are wrong ..

Comment: The MUI styling itself should be overriding the outside CSS, since it creates custom class names for higher specificity, so the border issue is a little surprising to me. I'd want to inspect the inputs, etc. closely using the dev tools to confirm exactly what properties are getting overridden and by what source. Maybe MUI's styles provider can help [MUI faq](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-arent-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds)?  Or globals [https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#global-css](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#global-css)?